# webupd8 JAVA_HOME not set after installing oracle-java8-set-default

Tags: java, environment, linux-mint

I'm following this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) to install Oracle Java 8.

Maybe I got this wrong, but I suppose JAVA_HOME should be set after installing `oracle-java8-set-default`.

If I `echo $JAVA_HOME` or `printenv | grep -i java` nothing comes up. I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 (Rebecca)

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME will not be set by the webupd8 method, and you don't normally need it (because the `update-java-alternatives` script manages the environment). If you're looking for the folder it's under "/usr/lib/jvm" and you can certainly do

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

and you can also test which Java is active with

```
java -version
```

or

```
java -fullversion
```

Comment: alright, I thought such variable would set. Thanks!

Comment: actually, http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html says doing a 'sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default' would set them (although that didn't work for me).

Comment: All Java environment variables are set in `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`, which is a file installed by `oracle-java8-set-default` and is read by the shell on start-up.

Answer (score 13):

You need to run also the command:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

as described in [WebUpd8 site](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html), then you need to logout and login back again, since the specific command creates two files under /etc/profile.d, named jdk.sh and jdk.csh which populate the environment with JAVA_HOME etc.

Comment: "you need to logout and login back again" that was the missing piece for me!

Comment: Pardon me but from the question I infer that the user already did that and he didn't get the result he was expecting (that is, having, among maybe others, the JAVA_HOME environment var set up.

Comment: Thanks.  This answer indirectly explains how to **get rid** of `JAVA_HOME` too.  i.e. `rm -rf /etc/profile.d/jdk.*`.  I've purged the `webupd8` packages, but this variable was sticking and breaking stuff.  This post was the only place I found explaining where the remnants were located.